# How to combine Swift sort methods with Realm containers?

Tags: swift, sorting, realm

I would like to perform a Swift sort on a Realm `Results` container like

```
let swiftArray = realm.objects(Parent).sort{$0.children.count > $1.children.count}
```

Would it be possible to convert `swiftArray` back to `Results<T>`? The rest of my code works with Realm containers and converting everything to Swift arrays will probably reduce performance.

Or, even better, would it (ever) be possible to use Swift sort methods directly on Realm containers?

Comment: I'm understanding that you are not able to access to the objects that there were in your results array. 

If you want to get your swiftArray of type Results<T> add : 
`as! [THE_TYPE_YOU_WANT]` . Just replace "THE_TYPE_YOU_WANT" with the objects that must contains your array and you should be able to work with your Real containers. Tell me if I misunderstood your problem

Comment: I am able to access both types. Since Results<T> data are initialized lazy I prefer to work with this type by default. However, In some situations I need more complex sorting. Only in these situations it seems necessary to convert data to Swift arrays. Since the rest of my code expects data of Results<T> type, my thoughts were that I have two options: 1) to convert the Swift array back to Results<T> or 2) to modify all my code to support both Results<T> and Swift arrays simultaneously (without needing to convert Results<T> where it is not required). Unfortunately, I don’t know how to do that.

Comment: Casting the data to [Parent] will give an error stating "Cannot assign value of type '[Parent]' to type 'Results<Parent>!'". I would appreciate to hear whether you have other thoughts on this.

Comment: What is Results ? It should be an Array.

Comment: Results<T> is a container type used in Realm and implements the RealmCollectionType protocol.

Comment: So use  `as! Results<Parent> `

Comment: Just downcasting would never work since the types are unrelated. I expect that some conversion is required (if possible at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible at the moment. Ideally, you would be able to sort the items via Realm using `.sorted("children.count")`, but at the time of writing, Realm doesn't support key path sorting.

There's [an issue on the Realm GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1277) account tracking this issue. Please go there and +1 it to let the other Realm engineers know you want it. :)

If your current solution where you're creating a manually sorted Swift array isn't acceptable, something you could consider doing is adding another property to your `Parent` model object called `numberOfChildren` and store the children count there. While this does mean making your data slightly redundant and increasing maintenance a bit, you could then use that property to sort your results while keeping it entirely within Realm. :)

Comment: I was not aware of this issue on GitHub, but it is exactly about the same issue. It would be a great addition to Realm! Although it is not my preference, I will indeed consider to save some data redundant for the time being.